# How to select two properties from array of objects as array on knex?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

I use **objextion.js** and **knex** on project.

And I wanna select two properties from relation and and nest them in an array. That relation contains array of object with properties **lat** and **lng**, I need receive array of arrays with lat and lng  `[[lat, lng]]`. How I understand I must select fields and use **raw** from objection to write array_agg for contain my props, but I don't understand what syntax there must be.

In **modifyGraph** with select I receive array of objects with **lng** and **lat**

**My request**

```
const query = Restaurants
    .query()
    .withGraphFetched({
      schedule: true,
    })
    .skipUndefined();

  if (lat && lng) {
    query.withGraphFetched({
      areas: {
        area: {
          coordinates: true,
        },
      },
    }).modifyGraph('areas.area.coordinates', (builder) => {
      builder.select([
        'lat',
        'lng',
      ]);
    });
  }

  return query
    .andWhere(restFields)
    .andWhere('name', 'ilike', `%${search}%`);
};
```

**My response from db**

```
[
  AreasCoordinatesModel { lat: -46.653, lng: -23.543 },
  AreasCoordinatesModel { lat: -46.634, lng: -23.5346 },
]
```

**And must be**

```
[
 [ -46.653, -23.543 ],
 [ -46.634,-23.5346 ]
]
```

Comment: can't you write a custom JS function that takes the db response and converts it to what you need?

Comment: @tHeSiD Unfortunately, after receiving this list, 2 nested cycles have already passed, I would not want to increase the number of cycles, I am sure that I can get my properties as an array from the database.

Comment: Implement it in the `afterFind` hook? https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/instance-methods.html#afterfind
Or just create a specific method as @tHeSiD said

Answer (score 0):

you can map all the objects in the array on the return using

```js
return (query
    .andWhere(restFields)
    .andWhere('name', 'ilike', `%${search}%`)).map(Object.values);
```

and it will return like you wanted.